# Response Code: 404 when calling Google Analytics admin api

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics-api

when i am calling

```
function getDataStreams() {
  const parent = 'properties/<my_property>'
  try {
    const request = {
      parent
    };
    Logger.log(request);

    const response = AnalyticsAdmin.Properties.DataStreams.list(request);
    Logger.log(response);
    return response;
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.stack)
  }

}
```

i am getting an error:

```
HttpResponseException: Response Code: 404. Message: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//w....
```

my function code seems to be valid, the service is enabled and the property exists (i am able to run the api call using api explorer and SDK). Do you have an idea what is going wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: What does you request look like when using the API explorer ? SDK?

Comment: async function getDataStreams(parent) {
    const request = {
        parent
    };
    const [streams] = await analyticsAdminClient.listDataStreams(request);
}
pretty the same...

Comment: Should it not be `const request = { "parent": parent}`?

Comment: nope, this syntax works fine on other requests (like listing properties `const request = {
    filter
  };
  const { properties } = await AnalyticsAdmin.Properties.list(request);`)

Comment: I am getting the same error. Did you manage to resolve this?